# How can I place 2 for loops under a if condition in a single line shell script?

Tags: shell

I want to write the following

```
if true
then
    for ....
    for ....
fi
```

as single line :
`if true; then for ......; for ......; done; fi;`

I tried getting `if true; then for ......; for ......; done; fi;`
and i am getting a syntax error

Comment: [Looks like XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @GillesQuénot i need it to be a single line command. it is used in a groovy script

Comment: What is `....`?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if true; then for i in {0..2}; do echo "$i"; done; for j in {a..c}; do echo "$j"; done; fi
```

```
0
1
2
a
b
c
```